# Does IPv6 Prefix Delegation work with SLAAC, without the need of a DHCPv6 server/client?

Tags: ipv6, dhcpv6, prefix

All the (cisco) documentation I found about this topic always uses a DHCPv6 server or client to configure Prefix Delegation. But I never read that this is a requirement.

Can Prefix Delegation be configured without a DHCPv6 server or client?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prefix delegation is a DHCPv6 option. You cannot do it without DHCP.

Here is the RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3633